# Fechar o DataInputStream sempre fecha o InputStream?

Tags: java, socket, inputstream

Eu preciso usar temporariamente um  **DataInputStream** com um inputStream de um socket.

Eu preciso usar close no **DataInputStream**?
E se eu usar eu estaria fechando o inputStream do socket também ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você fechar o DataInputStream, ele vai fechar a stream que você passou no seu construtor (no seu caso, a inputStream do socket).

Da documentação de [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), na seção *métodos herdados da classe FilterInputStream* tem o link pro método [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#close()). Clicando nele a descrição fala que ele chama o `close` na *inner stream* (*"This method simply performs in.close().")*.

Comment: Então eu deve simplesmente ignorar , e não fechá-lo?

Comment: Depende; quando você não tiver mais usando o DataInputStream, você ainda quer usar o inputStream do socket? Se sim, então não deve fechá-lo.